# Getting List index out of bounds: 3 error while dynamically deleting rows

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting the below error while dynamically deleting rows. Kindly help in resolving the issue.

**Error**

> System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 3
>   Error is in expression '{!deleteRow}' in component  in page autopopu: Class.RFPController.deleteRow: line 86, column 1
>   Class.RFPController.deleteRow: line 86, column 1

**Apex Class**

```
public with sharing class RFPController{

    public RFP__c accounts;
        public Custom_Package__c del;
        public List < Custom_Package__c > addattendeeList {get;set;}
        public List < Custom_Package__c > delattendeeList {get;set;}
        public List < Custom_Package__c > attendeeList {get;set;}
        public Integer totalCount {get;set;}
        public Integer rowIndex {get;set;}
        public Integer deleterowIndex {get;set;}
        public List < Custom_Package__c > delAttendees {get;set;}
        public Boolean isRerender{get;set;}
        public String S {get;set;}
        private List<Custom_Package__c>  acc {get;set;}

        public RFPController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

                isRerender = false;
                accounts =  (RFP__c )controller.getRecord();
                String S = 'Select id, Name, Market__c, State__c, First_Issue__c,Last_Issue__c,Circulation__c,Space_Unit__c,Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c,Space_Discount__c from Custom_Package__c WHERE Name = :S';
                //totalCount = attendeeList.size();
                attendeeList  = Database.Query(S);
                attendeeList = new List < Custom_Package__c >();
                for(integer i=0;i<1;i++){ 
                attendeeList .add(new Custom_Package__c ());
                }
                delattendeeList = new List < Custom_Package__c > ();
                delattendees = new List < Custom_Package__c > ();

                accounts.Rep_Name__c= Userinfo.getuserId();






        }

        public void addRow() {
                isRerender = true;
                rowIndex = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndex'));



                //rowIndex1 = rowIndex1 +1;
               addattendeeList = new List < Custom_Package__c > ();
                attendeeList.add(new Custom_Package__c ());
        }

        public void fetchRelatedAccountData(){
        system.debug('@@@@' + S);
                acc = new List<Custom_Package__c>();
                acc = [SELECT ID, Name, Market__c, State__c,Circulation__c,First_Issue__c,Last_Issue__c,Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c,Space_Discount__c,Space_Unit__c FROM Custom_Package__c WHERE Name = :S];
                integer c=0;
                map<String, integer> m = new map<string, integer>();
                m.put(acc[0].id, c++);

               if(rowIndex ==null)
                {
                rowIndex =0;
               }


                attendeeList[rowIndex ].Name = acc[0].Name;
                attendeeList[rowIndex ].Market__c= acc[0].Market__c;
                attendeeList[rowIndex ].State__c= acc[0].State__c;
                attendeeList[rowIndex ].Circulation__c= acc[0].Circulation__c;
                attendeeList[rowIndex ].First_Issue__c= acc[0].First_Issue__c;
                attendeeList[rowIndex ].Last_Issue__c= acc[0].Last_Issue__c;
                attendeeList[rowIndex].Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c= acc[0].Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c;





                system.debug('@@@@@@' + rowIndex);

        }


        public void deleteRow() {

                //rowIndex = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndex'));
                deleterowIndex = rowIndex-1; 
               System.debug('rowbe deleted ' + (rowIndex));
               System.debug('rowm to be deleted ' + attendeeList[rowIndex]);
                del = attendeeList.remove((deleterowIndex ));
              delattendeeList.add(del);
                 deleterowIndex = rowIndex-1; 


        }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="RFP__c" extensions="RFPController" sidebar="false">

<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock id="pb">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
         </apex:pageBlockButtons>

<apex:pageMessages />
      <apex:outputText rendered="{!isRerender}">

      </apex:outputText>      
      <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!0}"/>
      <apex:variable var="deleterowNumber" value="{!0}"/>

      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Child RFP Details" collapsible="false">

        <apex:pageBlockTable id="thetable"  var="acc" value="{!attendeeList}" rowClasses="oddrow,evenrow" onRowMouseOver="removeHighlight(this)">

             <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
            <apex:commandLink value="Copy" reRender="pb" onclick="testMe(event)"/>
          </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Custom Package Input" >
            <apex:inputText value="{!S}">
               <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!fetchRelatedAccountData}" rerender="thetable" />

            </apex:inputtext>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Custom Package" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Name}" style="width:300px" id="cp1"/>
          </apex:column>

          <apex:column headerValue="Market" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Market__c}" id="mar1"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="State" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.State__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="First Issue" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.First_Issue__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Last Issue" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Last_Issue__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Circulation" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Circulation__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Space Unit" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Space_Unit__c }"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Space Discount">
          <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Space_Discount__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
           <apex:column headerValue="Per Unit Open Rate">
          <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow}">

              <!--<apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}"/>-->

            </apex:commandButton>
            <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber+1}"/>

          </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
      <!-- </apex:pageblockSection> -->
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!addRow}" value="Add Row" reRender="pb"> 

      <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}"/>

       </apex:commandButton>
    <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber+1}"/>
      <script>
      function testMe(event){
               var current= event.target.parentElement.id;              
               index = Number(current.split(":thetable:")[1].split(":")[0]);
               if(index==0) 
               return;
    var tbody_tr = document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id2:pb:j_id40:thetable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var trLength= tbody_tr.length;
    var sTD1= document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id2:pb:j_id40:thetable:'+(index-1)+':cp1').value;
    document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id2:pb:j_id40:thetable:'+index+':cp1').value = sTD1;
}   
      </script>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Most possible reason is the rowIndex you passed through url does not match the existing records' amount in your table. Or otherwise you didn't pass one.

Comment: as an aside, anytime I see an index decremented twice in the controller method and incremented in the VF page I ask myself - surely there is a simpler, cleaner implementation - this could be the cause of your issues

Comment: can u let me know wht modification i need to do